# How to measure AICc for a bagged time series

Tags: r, forecasting

This comes from the text Forecasting Principles and Practice, [Bootrapping instructions](https://otexts.com/fpp3/bootstrap.html) but I don't see how to calculate AICc for bagged models.

```
library(fpp3)
library(tidyverse)
cement <- aus_production |>
  filter(year(Quarter) >= 1988) |>
  select(Quarter, Cement)
cement_stl <- cement |>
  model(stl = STL(Cement))
```

Next, the bootstrapped values are calculated by creating a number of simulations (I'll set it to 10 so it runs fast)

```
sim <- cement_stl |>
  generate(new_data = cement, times = 10,
           bootstrap_block_size = 8) |>
  select(-.model, -Cement)
```

So far, this is great. We can make a forecast, like this:

```
ets_forecasts <- sim |>
  model(ets = ETS(.sim)) |>
  forecast(h = 12)
```

Next we average the forecasts, again an easy process in the book:

```
bagged <- ets_forecasts |>
  summarise(bagged_mean = mean(.mean))
```

This is where I'm stuck. I'm trying to calculate the AICc value, and nothing is working. For example:

```
glance(bagged)
accuracy(bagged)
glance(ets_forecasts)
accuracy(object = bagged, data = ets_forecasts)
```

all return an error message such as:

```
Error in UseMethod("glance") : 
  no applicable method for 'accuracy' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_ts', 'tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AICc is a function of the likelihood and the number of parameters in the underlying model, so you need to be able to write down a model and a likelihood. With bagging, you are averaging over many models, so there is no single underlying model. You could approximate the likelihood by assuming the residuals are Gaussian, but it is not clear what the number of parameters should be.